# How to use redshift copy command in psycopg2 identifier

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I set following python lambda code which execute `COPY` command to redshift.

```
bucket_name = get_bucket_name(event)
file_name = get_file_name(event)

table = bucket_name.replace('-','_')
url = f's3://{bucket_name}/{file_name}'
```

```
    query = sql.SQL(''' truncate test_Schema.{};
            commit;
            copy test_Schema.{}
            from {}
            iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::123344:role/test'
            timeformat as 'auto'
            ACCEPTINVCHARS
            CSV;''').format(*map(sql.Identifier,(table,table,url)))
    
    print(query)
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute(query, (url,))
    con.commit()
```

By using identifier, I can use variables and set S3 bucket destination.

But it returned following errors. it seems that double quotation caused error..

```
truncate test_Schema."test";
commit;
copy jp_icqa_ddl."operation_defect_detail"
from "s3://test_Schema/test_20210816.csv"
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::123344:role/test'
timeformat as 'auto'
ACCEPTINVCHARS
CSV; 

[ERROR] SyntaxError: syntax error at or near ""s3://test_Schema/test_20210816.csv""
LINE 4:             from "s3://test_Schema/test_20210816...
                         ^

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/s3-to-redshift.py", line 63, in lambda_handler
    cur.execute(query, (url,))
```

Are there any way to avoid this ?

How can I handle double quotation in identifier ?

Thanks

Comment: before `cur = con.cursor()` do `print(query)` - you will get the output in cloudwatch. share the output.

Comment: try to use f string when you create the query. It makes the code more readable. see https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Answer (score 1):

Though this is not the exact answer to your question, here is a better solution that doesn't require a database connection string.

I recommend using Redshift Data API in lambda to load data into Redshift from S3.
You can get rid of `psycopgs2` package and use built-in `boto3` package in lambda.

This will run copy query asynchronously and lambda function won't take more than a few seconds to run it.

I use [sentry_sdk](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python) to get notifications of runtime error from lambda.

```
import boto3
import sentry_sdk
from sentry_sdk.integrations.aws_lambda import AwsLambdaIntegration

sentry_sdk.init(
    "https://aaaaaa@aaaa.ingest.sentry.io/aaaaaa",
    integrations=[AwsLambdaIntegration(timeout_warning=True)],
    traces_sample_rate=0
)


def execute_redshift_query(sql):
    data_client = boto3.client('redshift-data')
    data_client.execute_statement(
        ClusterIdentifier='redshift-cluster-test',
        Database='db',
        DbUser='db_user',
        Sql=sql,
        StatementName='Test query',
        WithEvent=True,
    )


def handler(event, context):
    query = """
    copy schema.test_table
    from 's3://test-bucket/test.csv'
    IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/TestRole'
    region 'us-east-1'
    ignoreheader 1 csv delimiter ','
    """
    execute_redshift_query(query)
    return True
```

And another lambda function to send error notification if copy query fails.
You can add EventBridge lambda trigger using the rule in screenshot below.
[image]

Here is lambda code to send error notification.

```
import sentry_sdk
from sentry_sdk.integrations.aws_lambda import AwsLambdaIntegration

sentry_sdk.init(
    "https://aaaa@aaa.ingest.sentry.io/aaaaa",
    integrations=[AwsLambdaIntegration(timeout_warning=True)],
    traces_sample_rate=0
)


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        if event["detail"]["state"] != "FINISHED":
            raise ValueError(str(event))
    except Exception as e:
        sentry_sdk.capture_exception(e)
    return True
```

You can identify which copy query failed by using `StatementName` defined in the first lambda function.

Hope it is helpful.